# PostURL in WEBVIEW in android

Tags: android, post, webview, http-post

I want to post data using webview in android. Tried below code,

```
String postdata="username=abcd";
myWebView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```

but was not getting the desired output. Please let me know if there is any alternate way to post data in webview.

The same was done in IOS and was sucessfully implemented. shown below is the code in IOS:

```
NSString *loginUrl = @"https://www.abcdefgh.com/SellOnline/j_spring_check";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:loginUrl];
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // POST the username password
    [requestObj setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"agent=%@", @"839878"];
    NSData *data = [postString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [requestObj setHTTPBody:data];

    self.webview.delegate = self;
    [self.webview loadRequest:requestObj];\
```

Comment: What output are you getting? Because this looks right to me, perhaps you forgot something in your postdata? I need more information.

Comment: i want the page in the webview to open with a login session, but now it is asking me for login credentials.

Comment: you mean you are login to native application say suing webservice(http call) and some further process you want do through webview with same session of httpclient. In short you are trying to sync cookies between webview and Httpclient right?

Comment: @Biraj- yes you are right. After native login,i am trying to post url in webview

Comment: Change Base64 With "UTF-8" this may help

Answer (score -1):

```
out_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/txtProgress"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:progress="50"
                android:progressTint="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Progress"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>  

Java
```